# How to get an embed object when don't know its id?

Tags: javascript, html

My html has an extension which embeded by other application:

```
document.documentElement.appendChild((function () {
    var objectElement = document.createElement("embed");
    objectElement.setAttribute("id", "my-plugin");
    objectElement.setAttribute("type", "application/x-my-app");
    objectElement.setAttribute("width", "0");
    objectElement.setAttribute("height", "0");
    return objectElement;
}()));
```

Normally we get this object by its id: `var plugin = document.getElementById("my-plugin");`

The problem here is, the object is injected by other apps and its ID could vary. I only know its MIME type is "x-my-app", but looks like there is no `getElementByType()` to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [sufficiently advanced browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector) you can use `querySelector()`/`querySelectorAll()`:

```
document.querySelector("embed[type='application/x-my-app']")
```

If using jQuery, the following will work even on less sufficiently advanced browsers:

```
$("embed[type='application/x-my-app']")
```

If neither, you can loop over all the `<embed>` tags:

```
result = [];
var embeds = document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
for (var i = 0; i < embeds.length; i++) {
    var embed = embeds[i];
    if (embed.type === type) {
        result.push(embed);
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/73Lum/1/) of all three.

Comment: I didn't think you were supposed to use the structure `for (var i in embeds)` on arrays.

Comment: @jfriend00: Right, I forgot about monkey-patching libraries. (Rubyland has a lot to answer for.)

Comment: Thanks @Inerdial, `document.querySelector("embed[type='application/x-my-app']")` works in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to find it based on tag type `embed` and the things you do know around it.  For example if your HTML was like this where the embed ID us unknown:

```
<div id="homepage">
<div class="decorativeFrame">
<embed id="sk930123">
...
</embed>
</div>
</div>
```

Then, you would find it like this:

```
var embeds = document.getElementById("homepage").getElementsByTagName("embed");
// operate on embeds[0]
```

If there are multiple embeds within the scope you're looking, then you may have to loop through all that are found and examine some attribute of the embed tag to identify the one you're looking for.

If you show us what the neighboring HTML is like, we could find tune exactly how you would fine it.

Comment: It is a simple background html file that contains no neighboring elements around the embed object. Haven't tried it but I think it should help if a browser doesn't support `querySelector()`

Comment: There can't be nothing around the embed object.  It has to be in some other object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getElementsByTagName()` and loop through the results until you find one with the correct media type.

Comment: ... or even try to use querySelector("embed[type="application/x-my-app"), when the targeted environment supports that.